# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method in "new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()"

Tags: java, hibernate

I am seeing `NullPointerException` when I try to `buildSessionFactory`. However, on clicking the exception object in Eclipse's debug mode, the message I see is `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.`

I am seeing this behavior only after having introduced a new `Entity` class. The table to which the class is bound, exists. There are no typos. `hibernate.cfg.xml` is parsed successfully too. A fatal exception is thrown after hibernate tries to bind the new class to the table.

1. hibernate.cfg.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@lvsspldb06.qa.xxxx.com:1556:ICMDBTST</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ICMAPP</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ICMAPP</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.xxxx.top.entity.Release"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.xxxx.top.entity.Package"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.xxxx.top.entity.Top"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.xxxx.top.entity.PortAssignment"></mapping>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

2. `desc package_portassignment;` gives an output. So that confirms that the table exists.
3. Console log

```
. . .
22:03:02.239 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Session-factory config [null] named class [com.xxxx.top.entity.Release] for mapping
22:03:03.031 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Session-factory config [null] named class [com.xxxx.top.entity.Package] for mapping
22:03:03.589 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Session-factory config [null] named class [com.xxxx.top.entity.Top] for mapping
22:03:04.076 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Session-factory config [null] named class [com.xxxx.top.entity.PortAssignment] for mapping
22:03:04.080 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
. . .
22:03:13.287 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Processing hbm.xml files
22:03:13.287 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Process annotated classes
22:03:13.305 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.xxxx.top.entity.Release
22:03:13.415 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3DiscriminatorColumn{logicalColumnName'DTYPE', discriminatorTypeName='string'}
22:03:13.422 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - No value specified for 'javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode'; using UNSPECIFIED
22:03:13.450 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name Release
22:03:13.470 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.xxxx.top.entity.Release on table release_release
22:03:13.567 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(release_release), mappingColumn=id, 
. . .
22:03:13.646 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3DiscriminatorColumn{logicalColumnName'DTYPE', discriminatorTypeName='string'}
22:03:13.646 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - No value specified for 'javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode'; using UNSPECIFIED
22:03:13.646 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name Package
22:03:13.647 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.xxxx.top.entity.Package on table package_package
. . .
22:03:13.699 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - No value specified for 'javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode'; using UNSPECIFIED
22:03:13.699 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name Top
22:03:13.700 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.xxxx.top.entity.Top on table top_top
22:03:13.710 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(top_top), mappingColumn=id, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=true}
. . .
22:03:13.719 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - No value specified for 'javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode'; using UNSPECIFIED
22:03:13.719 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name PortAssignment
22:03:13.719 [main] DEBUG o.h.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.xxxx.top.entity.PortAssignment on table package_portassignment
FATAL exception is thrown here
```

4. The newly added Entity class

[PortAssignment.java](https://gist.github.com/sriram-a/deeea954ee0102f1b121). Was not able to post it inside this question as stackoverflow was giving me much grief with the formatting.

Comment: can you add full stacktrace also?

Comment: I am seeing a `NullPointerException` with no stack trace info. The detailed messaged associated with the exception is empty too. When I try to inspect the exception object, the thread ends abruptly.

Comment: add more lines after `FATAL exception is thrown here`.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow me to add those lines because it thinks it is code which has not been formatted properly.  However, I can explain the fatal exception. The exception happens when I am try to initialize a static member during the class load time, which in turn throws an `ExceptionInInitializerError`. I will post the new class for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the new class and the error disappeared. I admit, I am embarrassed but I think there was a typo in the annotation `Column(name=...)` for one the properties.

I *suppose* this caused a `NullPointerException` in one of the internal classes of Hibernate (specifically `org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.XClass.getDeclaredProperties`).

Thanks Channa Jayamuni for your thoughts.